# Angular2, Typescript: Add an object to an object array of an object array of an object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to simply add an updated object to an object array the struggle comes because the array is nested in the below structure.

```
Parent Object
id;
subObject[];

Sub Object
id;
subSubObject[];

Sub Sub Object
name;
```

Parent Object > Sub Object > Sub Sub Object to be added to the array of the Sub Object.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: What's your query? Whats your expectation? Brief more...

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically, you can chain the push as shown below:

```
const example = {
    id: 1,
    subObject: [
        {
            id: 2,
            subSubObject: [
                {
                    name: 'Jackson'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

// Simplistic Example:
example.subObject[0].subSubObject.push({ name: 'Fenton' });
console.log(JSON.stringify(example));

// Assuming you want to push it onto a particular sub object:
example.subObject.find((item) => item.id === 2).subSubObject.push({ name: 'Toby' });
console.log(JSON.stringify(example));
```